# Add Control in a Form according to Observable return

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular-reactive-forms

I need to add a control to my form's array type, but I need to get the return of an Observable before to map the values ​​and then add it to the form.

In the code below an empty array control is inserted even if there is no observable value.

I need to ensure that before adding the control, within subscribe has returned all observable data.

The way it's done is inserting empty, I need to get the last value returned inside subscribe and then insert the control with the amount of users returned.

In my HTML I need to display checkbox with the users name and whether they are tagged or not recording in the array the id of the user and a boolean value for each.

**component.ts**

```
    users$ = this._store.select(usersSelectors.getUsers);

    this.myForm = this._formBuilder.group({
        // .... controls
    });

    this.users$.pipe(
        filter((data) => !!data),
        map(users => this._formBuilder.array(users.map(() => new FormControl(false))))
    ).subscribe(usersArray => 
        this.myForm.addControl('users', usersArray)
    );
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <label for="users">Users</label>
  <div id="users" class="row">
    <div class="checkbox" class="col-sm-4"
      formArrayName="users"
      *ngFor="let item of myForm.get('users').controls; let i = index" >
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i"> {{ users$[i].name }}
      </label>
    </div>
```

return from users$:

```
0: {subscriber: false, avatar: "", name: "Paul", id: "eXrrdOfmUGYHFIOVCWjBnAO7PZ52" …}
1: {subscriber: true, avatar: "", name: "Will", id: "NoQMVGnCA6VPc42ksIa6AqZZNWL2" …}
```

**When marking the user the users control should be as follows.**

```
users: [
{eXrrdOfmUGYHFIOVCWjBnAO7PZ52: false}
{NoQMVGnCA6VPc42ksIa6AqZZNWL2: true}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the form first and then `push` controls to the form array depending on the Observable value. Something along the lines of this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  users;
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  get usersForm() {
    return (<FormArray>this.form.get('users')).controls;
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.form = this.fb.group({
      users: this.fb.array([])
    });

    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .subscribe(users => {
        this.users = users;
        this.users.forEach(user => {
          if(typeof(user) == typeof(true)) this.usersForm.push(this.fb.control([user.tagged]));
        });
        console.log('Users Form: ', this.usersForm);
      });
  }
}
```

Here's a **[Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cye51p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)** for the same.

Comment: it works but the problem is that 5 users are being displayed when there is only 2, why is it?

Comment: 0: true
1: false
2: ["eXrrdOfmUGYHFIOVCWjBnAO7PZ52"]
3: ["NoQMVGnCA6VPc42ksIa6AqZZNWL2"]
4: ["eXrrdOfmUGYHFIOVCWjBnAO7PZ52"]

Comment: The array that you just sent has 5 elements.

Comment: Yes but within the observable there are only 2 users, I need to write the ids of this two users with false or true value as follows. [{id: id1: false}, {id: id2: true}]

Comment: There should only be two objects inside the array but it is coming more I do not know the reason ... this happens when I update the page with F5.

Comment: Please post the data that you're getting for the `users` as well. Better, create a stackblitz if possible.

Comment: I've added a check for when the type of user is a boolean. Check if that works.